# Python, centering a character with PIL

Tags: python, text, unicode, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw a single large character using PIL but not all chars are the same width, ex.: 'M' is wider then 'I' and I want them to be centered/justified. I looked into draw.gettext and draw.getsize and account for the width of the canvas to no avail.

Here is my code so far.

```
font_size=160
width = 200
height = 200
unicode_text = u"\u2104"
im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), 'white' )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw (im)
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("DejaVuSans.ttf", font_size)
draw.text ((0,0), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill='black')
im.save("text.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably worked this out for yourself by now. What you needed to know was about the availability of `draw.textsize`.

```
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
>>> from PIL import ImageDraw
>>> from PIL import ImageFont
>>> unicode_text = u"\u2104"
>>> im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (200,200), 'white' )
>>> draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
>>> unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("DejaVuSans.ttf", 160)
>>> text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(unicode_text, font=unicode_font)
>>> draw.text(((200-text_width)//2,(200-text_height)//2), unicode_text, font=unicode_font, fill='black')
>>> im.save('it.png')
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, i did find a different way to solve it just seconds before your posting, I like your solution better.  I ended up using the tuple from size = unicode_font.getsize(unicode_text)

Comment: You're welcome. Did the other method make a difference?